# Issues with adding ionic-service-core

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm working on adding in ionic-service-core in order to add notifications to an ionic project I'm working on. I can't however, get the service core to install. Any attempts to do so result in this:

```
Failed to find the bower component "ionic-service-core".
Are you sure it exists? (CLI v1.4.0-alpha.6)

Your system information:

OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.10.33
Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Ionic Version: 1.0.0-rc.5
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.0-alpha.6
Xcode version: Xcode 6.3.1 Build version 6D1002 
ios-sim version: Not installed
```

Anyone have any experience working with ionic and the new services packages? Any clue what would cause this?

Comment: How are you adding it? With "ionic add ionic-service-core"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the whole thing is a permissions issue with the users .config file. If you simply delete the .config folder sitting at Users/username/.config, and retry adding the components, they'll work.

Comment: I did a recursive permissions change on the parent folder (via OS X get info)

Comment: @Jackson what were the permission changes? Do you remember?

Comment: @leonsas I want to say it was the entire app folder. Not sure how you would do it in windows but on Linux machines (non osx) you could probably do `chmod -R g+w` and or `chmod -R u+w`

Answer (score 6):

To test that you have bower installed, run the command 
`bower`.
 If this is unrecognized,
install with command
 `npm install -g bower`
and afterwards run 
`ionic add ionic-service-core`.

This worked for me in Windows.

Comment: This helped me in finding out that the issue was in fact related to permissions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick that works for me, you can first use *bower install* to install your package, and then use *ionic add* that will find the bower package previously installed :

1. **bower install** myPackage
2. **ionic add** myPackage

Works for me because of being behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had also same issue. Run the below two commands and it should work.

```
npm install -g bower
bower install ionic-service-core --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a permissions issue (on OSX).

Can be fixed using `chmod 755 ~/.config`

That changes the permissions of the folder to rwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above, but what really worked for me was this,hope this help someone. 
this is where i found it.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-platform-web-client/issues/29

```
ionic config build
```